# Difference between Static and Non-Static methods/Subroutines

Tags: java, static-methods, subroutine, non-static

I was reading a java book, where I came across this statement:

**`So, every subroutine is contained either in a class or in an object`**

I'm really confused why does it say **`"class or in an object"`**

I would like some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this example

```
public class Demo {

    public static void classMethod() {
        System.out.println("Call to static method");
    }

    public void objectMethod() {
        System.out.println("Call to object method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = null;
        demo.classMethod();
        //demo.objectMethod();// throws NPE if uncommented
    }
}
```

This code will work (even if the `demo` variable is `null`) because static method `classMethod` is contained within the class `Demo`. The commented line will throw a `NullPointerException` because the method `objectMethod` is not contained in the class but in the object so will need an instance of `Demo` class to call it.

Comment: are you really showing a static call on an instance variable to a rookie learning java?

Answer (score 1):

Subroutine is a method written inside a class. We use them to do various tasks. That statement states that these methods/subroutines are written in an object or a class.

If we have an object instantiated, it will create new methods for every `non-static` method for that object which were defined in the class of the object. Hence those `non-static` methods/subroutines are in the object.

But if the class is a `static` class, we can't have any objects from it. But we can use subroutines/methods of that class. So, they are in a `Class`

That's what your statement says.

**EDIT:**

I thought to give an example for this.

```
public class ExampleClass {

  public String getNonStaticString() {
    return "This String is From Non-Static Method";
  }

  public static String getStaticString() {
    return "This String is From Static Method"
  }
}
```

Then, if you need to get the `static` String, all you have to do is

```
String staticString = ExampleClass.getStaticString();
```

Note that I havn't created an object from the `ExampleClass` Here. I just used the method.

But, if you need to get the `String` from the `non-static` method, you should instantiate an object first.

```
ExampleClass exampleObject = new ExampleClass();
String nonStaticString = exampleObject.getNonStaticString();
```

Comment: and if a a member is static, so without creating an object how can we use those static members

Comment: We can call the class itself.

Comment: @SumeetChand I think you should accept an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

static methods also known as class method. Static method associated only with the class and not with any specific instance of that class(object).

Comment: can you explain in terms of subroutines ?

Comment: in java subroutines often called methods. 
Example:
class Number {
getValue();

Comment: that means if i declare something in a class to be static, then an instance of that class cannot access it ?

Comment: in java subroutines often called methods. 
Example of static vs non-static method:
class Number {
 private int value;

 public static Number getRandomNumber() {
  Number n = /* generate some number */
  return N
 }
 public int getValue() {
  return value;
 }
}

getValue - is a method of object that returns actual value of that Number object
getRandomNumber - is a static method(or subroutine) that can be called without any existing Number instance.

Answer (score 0):

> So, every subroutine is contained either in a class or in an object

The statement is technically not 100% correct.

First of all, subroutines in java are commonly called methods. The following two terms are often used interchangeably:

**Method**: A subroutine working with an object instance, `this`.

**Function**: A subroutine *not* working with an object instance.

---

Here is an example scenario which should you get an idea what that means:

```
public class Circle {
    //region static code
    //we cannot call "this" in a static context, main(String[]) is no exception here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle a = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
        Circle b = new Circle(10, 10, 2);
        System.out.println("a                  = " + a);
        System.out.println("b                  = " + b);
        System.out.println("circumference of a = " + a.getCircumference());
        System.out.println("circumference of b = " + b.getCircumference());
        System.out.println("area of a          = " + a.getArea());
        System.out.println("area of b          = " + b.getArea());
        System.out.println("distance of a, b   = " + distance(a, b));
        System.out.println("a, b intersect     = " + (intersects(a, b) ? "yes" : "no"));
    }

    //we cannot call "this" in a static context, but we have the circles a, b as parameters we can use to calculate their distance
    public static double distance(Circle a, Circle b) {
        return Math.sqrt(squared(a.x - b.x) + squared(a.y - b.y));

    }

    //we cannot call "this" in a static context, but we have the circles a, b as parameters we can use to check for an intersection
    public static boolean intersects(Circle a, Circle b) {
        return a.radius + b.radius > distance(a, b);

    }

    //we cannot call "this" in a static context, but we have the number x as parameter we can use to calculate the square of
    public static double squared(double x) {
        return x * x;

    }

    //we cannot call "this" in a static context, but we have the number radius as parameter we can use to check if its value is in range
    public static void checkRadius(double radius) {
        if(radius < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("radius must be >= 0");
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region member / instance code
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double radius;

    public Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
        checkRadius(radius);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    //region getters and setters
    //we may refer to the instance variables with or without "this", sometimes it is necessary to clarify - see: setX(double)
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    //we may refer to the instance variables with or without "this", but in this case we have two variables with name "x"
    //if we write "x", the parameter is taken. for the circle's x coordinate, we need to clarify with "this.x"
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        checkRadius(radius);
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    //endregion

    //we may refer to the instance variables with or without "this", sometimes it is necessary to clarify - see: setX(double)
    public double getCircumference() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * squared(radius);
    }

    //we may refer to the instance variables with or without "this", sometimes it is necessary to clarify - see: setX(double)
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "circle at [" + x + ", " + y + "] with radius " + radius;
    }
    //endregion
}
```

**Output**:

```
a                  = circle at [0.0, 0.0] with radius 10.0
b                  = circle at [10.0, 10.0] with radius 2.0
circumference of a = 62.83185307179586
circumference of b = 12.566370614359172
area of a          = 314.1592653589793
area of b          = 12.566370614359172
distance of a, b   = 14.142135623730951
a, b intersect     = no
```